# Get output parameter value in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

My stored procedure has an output parameter:

```
@ID INT OUT
```

How can I retrieve this using ado.net?

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // add parameters

    conn.Open();

    // *** read output parameter here, how?
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 125):

The other response shows this, but essentially you just need to create a `SqlParameter`, set the `Direction` to `Output`, and add it to the `SqlCommand`'s `Parameters` collection.  Then execute the stored procedure and get the value of the parameter.

Using your code sample:

```
// SqlConnection and SqlCommand are IDisposable, so stack a couple using()'s
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn))
{
   // Create parameter with Direction as Output (and correct name and type)
   SqlParameter outputIdParam = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
   { 
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
   };

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(outputIdParam);

   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   // Some various ways to grab the output depending on how you would like to
   // handle a null value returned from the query (shown in comment for each).

   // Note: You can use either the SqlParameter variable declared
   // above or access it through the Parameters collection by name:
   //   outputIdParam.Value == cmd.Parameters["@ID"].Value

   // Throws FormatException
   int idFromString = int.Parse(outputIdParam.Value.ToString());

   // Throws InvalidCastException
   int idFromCast = (int)outputIdParam.Value; 

   // idAsNullableInt remains null
   int? idAsNullableInt = outputIdParam.Value as int?; 

   // idOrDefaultValue is 0 (or any other value specified to the ?? operator)
   int idOrDefaultValue = outputIdParam.Value as int? ?? default(int); 

   conn.Close();
}
```

Be careful when getting the `Parameters[].Value`, since the type needs to be cast from `object` to what you're declaring it as. And the `SqlDbType` used when you create the `SqlParameter` needs to match the type in the database. If you're going to just output it to the console, you may just be using `Parameters["@Param"].Value.ToString()` (either explictly or implicitly via a `Console.Write()` or `String.Format()` call).

EDIT: Over 3.5 years and almost 20k views and nobody had bothered to mention that it didn't even compile for the reason specified in my "be careful" comment in the original post. Nice. Fixed it based on good comments from @Walter Stabosz and @Stephen Kennedy and to match the update code edit in the question from @abatishchev.

Comment: You don't need `conn.Close()` as its inside a `using` block

Comment: I think your use of int.MaxValue as the Size property is incorrect. int.MaxValue is a constant with the value 2,147,483,647. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.size.aspx . The mistake is harmless in this example because the datatype is Int and "For fixed length data types, the value of Size is ignored.", but a zero would have sufficed.

Comment: .Value is of type object, so assigning it directly to an int without casting isn't going to work.

Comment: For those that are using a DataReader, you must close it or read to the end of the data before you can view the output parameters.

Answer (score 62):

For anyone looking to do something similar using a reader with the stored procedure, note that the reader must be closed to retrieve the output value.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection())
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // add parameters
    SqlParameter outputParam = cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    outputParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

    conn.Open();

    using(IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            //read in data
        }
    }
    // reader is closed/disposed after exiting the using statement
    int id = outputParam.Value;
}
```

Comment: I missed the fact that the reader must be closed before reading the output parameter. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 29):

Not my code, but a good example i think

source: http://www.eggheadcafe.com/PrintSearchContent.asp?LINKID=624

```cs
using System; 
using System.Data; 
using System.Data.SqlClient; 


class OutputParams 
{ 
    [STAThread] 
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    { 

    using( SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("server=(local);Database=Northwind;user id=sa;password=;")) 
    { 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CustOrderOne", cn); 
        cmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure ; 

        SqlParameter parm= new SqlParameter("@CustomerID",SqlDbType.NChar) ; 
        parm.Value="ALFKI"; 
        parm.Direction =ParameterDirection.Input ; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm); 

        SqlParameter parm2= new SqlParameter("@ProductName",SqlDbType.VarChar); 
        parm2.Size=50; 
        parm2.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm2); 

        SqlParameter parm3=new SqlParameter("@Quantity",SqlDbType.Int); 
        parm3.Direction=ParameterDirection.Output; 
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parm3);

        cn.Open(); 
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
        cn.Close(); 

        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@ProductName"].Value); 
        Console.WriteLine(cmd.Parameters["@Quantity"].Value.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Yep, this is correct. Just set the ParameterDirection property of the parameter. You don't need the cn.Close() line - the using{} block takes care of that.

Answer (score 8):

```
public static class SqlParameterExtensions
{
    public static T GetValueOrDefault<T>(this SqlParameter sqlParameter)
    {
        if (sqlParameter.Value == DBNull.Value 
            || sqlParameter.Value == null)
        {
            if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
                return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));

            return (default(T));
        }

        return (T)sqlParameter.Value;
    }
}


// Usage
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcedure", conn))
{
   SqlParameter outputIdParam = new SqlParameter("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
   { 
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output 
   };

   cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(outputIdParam);

   conn.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

   int result = outputIdParam.GetValueOrDefault<int>();
}
```

Comment: // Null value handling
   if ( null == arg || arg.Value == DBNull.Value || arg.Value == null ) {
    return ( default( T ) );
   }
   return (T) arg.Value;

Answer (score 6):

```
string ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
//Create the SqlCommand object
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(“spAddEmployee”, con);

//Specify that the SqlCommand is a stored procedure
cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//Add the input parameters to the command object
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@Name”, txtEmployeeName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@Gender”, ddlGender.SelectedValue);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(“@Salary”, txtSalary.Text);

//Add the output parameter to the command object
SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
outPutParameter.ParameterName = “@EmployeeId”;
outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);

//Open the connection and execute the query
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

//Retrieve the value of the output parameter
string EmployeeId = outPutParameter.Value.ToString();
}
```

Font http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/748619/ADO-NET-How-to-call-a-stored-procedure-with-output

Answer (score 3):

You can get your result by below code::

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sproc", conn);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    // add other parameters parameters

    //Add the output parameter to the command object
    SqlParameter outPutParameter = new SqlParameter();
    outPutParameter.ParameterName = "@Id";
    outPutParameter.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int;
    outPutParameter.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(outPutParameter);

    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Retrieve the value of the output parameter
    string Id = outPutParameter.Value.ToString();

    // *** read output parameter here, how?
    conn.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

***Create the SqlParamObject which would give you control to access methods on the parameters***

:

> SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();

*SET the Name for your paramter (it should b same as you would have declared a variable to hold the value in your DataBase)*

: `param.ParameterName = "@yourParamterName";`

*Clear the value holder to hold you output data*

: `param.Value = 0;`

*Set the Direction of your Choice (In your case it should be Output)*

: `param.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;`

Answer (score 1):

That looks more explicit for me:

> int? id = outputIdParam.Value is DbNull ? default(int?) : outputIdParam.Value;