# Communicate the logic used in a stored procedure to the calling C# application

Tags: c#, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure being called from a C# application. This stored procedure has two mutually exclusive code paths; They both return similar type of records, like this:

```
IF x=y
  SELECT colX, colY
  FROM TableA
ELSE
  SELECT colX,colY
  FROM TableA
  WHERE colX > 100
```

The task on hand involves writing the result of the sp call in a text file; the file's name depends on which of the two SELECT was executed. The name will be MyTextFile.txt or MyTextFileGT100.txt

How do I tell the C# app which of the two SELECT statements was executed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding another column is the wrong way to go -especially with larger result-sets. You'd be increasing data over the wire by polluting every single record with what should be a one-time value.

That said, I'd suggest an optional [output parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187004.aspx) for your stored procedure:

```
@branchId int = null output
```

Then set it within your logic blocks:

```
if x=y begin

  set @branchId = 1

  SELECT colX, colY
  FROM TableA

end else begin

  set @branchId = 2

  SELECT colX,colY
  FROM TableA
  WHERE colX > 100

end
```

This solution prevents changes to your result-sets and, provided that you always explicitly name procedure parameters, shouldn't affect any code. Further, you gain the added benefit of less data over the wire than the *add a column* option.

Answer (score 4):

You could use an output parameter in the stored proc and use that to decide the name of the text file.  See the links below for more info;

http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/110318

[Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net)

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```
IF x=y
  SELECT colX, colY, 'Method1' as method
  FROM TableA
ELSE
  SELECT colX,colY, 'Method2' as method
  FROM TableA
  WHERE colX > 100
```

Answer (score 3):

```
IF x=y
  SELECT colX, colY, 'case1' as WhichBranch
  FROM TableA
ELSE
  SELECT colX, colY, 'case2' as WhichBranch
  FROM TableA
  WHERE colX > 100
```

Comment: Exact same answer at the exact same time...  Impressive.

Answer (score 2):

Extend the Stored Procedure like this:

```
IF x=y
  SELECT colX, colY, 'MyTextFile.txt' AS FN
  FROM TableA
ELSE
  SELECT colX,colY, 'MyTextFileGT100.txt' AS FN
  FROM TableA
  WHERE colX > 100
```