# INSERT Auto Incremented Primary Key from TableA into FK of TableB

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I have two tables: `TableA` and `TableB`

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
[TableAId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL...

CREATE TABLE TableB (
[TableBId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[TableAID] [int] NOT NULL... -- this is the FK
```

Question: (as a C# developer)

I am writing a function that INSERTs into `TableA`. I need to grab the newly created primary key in `TableA` and insert it into the FK of `TableB` along with other data.

I've done this before, but I didn't like what I did which is lookup the `TableA` PK value immediately after the insert, store it as a variable and then insert it into `TableB`.

Can someone show me a more efficient way of doing this? Maybe using scope_identity() in a stored proc? A trigger won't work because I need the new PK back in my C# so I can add additional data before I insert into `TableB`. Plus, I want to lock both tables while this runs.

Thank you,
Robert

Comment: Do you want the answer in TSQL or c# - If c# are you using an ORM or raw ADO

Comment: What data access technology are you using? Pure ADO.NET? Entity Framework? Something else?

Comment: A fair number of major RDBMS providers allow `data change reference`s, which means you can `SELECT` off of only _changed_ (inserted, updated, deleted) rows - what system is your backend on?

Answer (score 1):

```
Declare @TableAId int

Insert TableA ( ... )
Values( ... )

Set @TableAId = Scope_Identity();

Insert TableB( TableAId, ... )
Values( @TableAId, ... )
```

It should be noted that it is possible to send this to SQL Server in a single batch. I.e., you can send this entire command text to SQL Server and execute all at once. Of course, you'll need to use parameters for all non-identity columns of table A *and* table B. For example:

```
const string sql = @"Declare @TableAId int

Insert TableA ( ... )
Values( ... )

Set @TableAId = Scope_Identity();

Insert TableB( TableAId, ... )
Values( @TableAId, ... )";

using ( var conn = new SqlConnection( ... ) )
{
    using ( var cmd = new SqlCommand( sql, conn ) )
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( @TableACol, ... );
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( @TableACol2, ... );
        ...
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue( @TableBCol, ... );

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Another choice if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later might be to use the [OUTPUT clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

```
Insert TableA( ... )
    Output Inserted.TableAId, @TableBCol1, @TableBCol2, ...
    Into TableB
Values( ... )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one stored procedure are inserting both sets of data at the same time then use this code.

```
DECLARE @id INT

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableA] VALUES (...)
SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO [dbo].[TableB] VALUES (@id ...)
```

If you are using raw ADO, then set `@id` as an OUTPUT parameter and use the return value in your second DB call. Refer to [here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net) of how to use an output parameter.

As for locking both tables, you can either wrap the call in a transaction (TSQL or ADO.NET) or set the `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` for the stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

This worked...

---

```
USE [TestDB01] 

GO 

SET ANSI_NULLS ON 

GO 

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 

GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_INSERT_INTO_Cars_And_Owners]
```

-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

```
         @PartnerId INT  
        , @Title NVARCHAR(100)  
        , @Description TEXT  
        , @IPAddress NVARCHAR(16)   
        , @IsCarOwner BIT
        , @OwnerTypeTypeID INT

AS 

BEGIN 

-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON; 


DECLARE @CarId INT 


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Cars] ( 
    PartnerId 
    , Title 
    , Description 
    , IPAddress 
    , IsCarOwner 
    ) 
VALUES ( 
    @PartnerId 
    , @Title 
    , @Description 
    , @IPAddress 
    , @IsCarOwner 
    )  


SET @CarId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Owners] ( 
    OwnerTypeTypeID 
    , CarId 
    ) 

VALUES ( 
    @OwnerTypeTypeID 
    , @CarId 
    )  

END
```