# Execute SQL Server Stored Procedure with SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet() and Get Return Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have an `SQL Server Stored Procedure`. This procedure have an output parameter.
On my `C#.NET` Appliaction, I execute this procedure via `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet()` and it returns a query result `DataSet`.
How can I get the output parameter from the stored procedure procedure while using `SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet()`.
Some article said that I need to use `SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery()` but I need the `DataSet` too.

This is my code:

```
        public DataSet GetDataPerTable(string spName, string a, string b, out int c)
        {
            try
            {
                c = 0;

                SqlParameter[] spParameter = new SqlParameter[3];

                spParameter[0] = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.Char, 4);
                spParameter[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                spParameter[0].Value = a;

                spParameter[1] = new SqlParameter("@b", SqlDbType.Char, 1);
                spParameter[1].Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
                spParameter[1].Value = b;

                spParameter[2] = new SqlParameter("@c", SqlDbType.Int);
                spParameter[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;                
                c = Convert.ToInt32(spParameter[2].Value);

                return SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Configuration.MyConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, spParameter);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

My `c` variable always return 0. Any Idea? Thanks in advance :)

My Procedure is about like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].SPR_MyProcedure (@a Char(4), @bChar(1), @c Int Output)  
SELECT * 
FROM MyTable
Set @c = 1
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`@c` isn't the a return value, it's an output parameter

Change

```
spParameter[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
```

to

```
 spParameter[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Also, you need to set your `c` variable after the call to `ExecuteDataset`
eg:

```
DataSet dataset = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(Configuration.MyConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, spName, spParameter);
c=(int)spParameter[2];
return dataset;
```

Comment: I've put my Stored Procedure script there :)

Comment: @WillyLazuardi Yes - it's definitely an output, not a returnvalue.

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `ParameterDirection.Output` for parameter `c`.
see [Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net)

`ParameterDirection.ReturnValue` is a return value of the whole stored procedure, 0 by default or a value specified in RETURN statement.

Answer (score 0):

SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet doesnt return output parameter. see this link

http://www.mediachase.com/documentation/fileuploader/Api/Mediachase.FileUploader.SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset_overload_5.html

for output parameter in every example they r using ExecuteNonQuery
see these aticles for output prameter

http://forums.asp.net/t/360456.aspx/1

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15666/Data-Access-Application-Block-NET-2-0-Get-Return-V

i hope it can help u