# Visual C# stored procedure asking for parameter that isn't needed

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE VendorsRowcount
    @RowCount int OUTPUT
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    SELECT * 
    FROM dbo.Vendors

    SET @RowCount = @@ROWCOUNT

    RETURN @RowCount
```

C#:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Pricer;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("VendorsRowcount", conn)
{
    CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
})
{
    conn.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

I am getting the error:

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'VendorsRowcount' expects parameter '@RowCount', which was not supplied.

I am just learning C# after setting out to learn VB and realizing that there are a lot more resources on the internet for C#.

This is probably a stupid question, but I have searched and maybe the terms I use are not the correct ones, because I can not find an answer.

To the best of my knowledge, I don't need to send a parameter because `@RowCount` is output.

Why do I get this error?

Comment: But you have `@RowCount` in your sp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a parameter in the stored procedure, it has no relevance the fact that is declared as OUTPUT. You need to pass it from your C# code. The alternative is to declare the parameter as optional as shown in another answer. However you have now a problem. How do you read back in your C# code that parameter's value?

First option, pass the parameter at the stored procedure and read it back

```
conn.Open();
SqlParameter prm = command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RowCount", SqlDbType.Int));
prm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine(prm.Value.ToString());
conn.Close();
```

Second option, set the parameter as optional, call the [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters(v=vs.110).aspx) method to fill the Parameter collection on the C# side and read it back. (Please read the remarks section in the link provided about the efficiency of this solution)

```
-- in the stored procedure
@RowCount int = 0 OUTPUT


conn.Open();
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(command);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters["@RowCount"].Value.ToString());
conn.Close();
```

However I am puzzled by the fact that you run a potentially costly `SELECT *` command  but you don't seems to be interested in the records returned.

In this context, a StoredProcedure seems to be excessive and adds a maintenance issue while you could get the row count simply writing:

```
conn.Open();
command.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Vendors";
int rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
Console.WriteLine(rowCount.ToString());
conn.Close();
```

Comment: This worked perfect.  And I know my code does/will be bad.  I am a network tech, not a programmer.  I was just told by my job to also become a programmer, so I'm trying.  I have about 3 weeks of experience with VB, and I'm on my first day of messing around with C#.  I'm sure theres plenty more stupid questions coming.

Comment: This seems as difficult as just typing out the query.  I was using stored procedures because I thought they would save time.

Comment: Unless really needed for complex operations or to squeeze the last bit of performance I suggest to stay away from SP for just a simple SELECT. For example you could get the COUNT(*) of your records in a simpler way

Comment: I'm looking into ado.net queries now.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass in that parameter. Here's a good example of how to do this:

[Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net)

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter should be optional, you must provide a default value in your Stored Procedure.

For example:
@RowCount int OUTPUT = 0