# Looping through gridview to send to stored procedure is stuck in loop

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, datagridview, foreach

I think i have been looking at this to long.. I have 2 gridviews with data. I want to loop through them and send each item to a stored procedure. That stored procedure checks for duplicates and sends back 1 if they exists and 0 if they don't. Well when I do the for each loop.. I get stuck. I have tried moving things around with no luck.. Here is my code:

```
public int IsExists() 
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSerials.Rows) 
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString)) 
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertReceiptSerials", con)) 
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ITEMNMBR", SqlDbType.Char).Value = OpenDescription.SelectedRow.Cells[5].Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RecLineID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(OpenDescription.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@RCPTLNNM", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(OpenDescription.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@POPRCTNM", SqlDbType.Char).Value = OpenDescription.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text.Trim();
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@SERLTNUM", SqlDbType.Char).Value = row.Cells[0].Text.Trim();
                SqlParameter parm = new SqlParameter("@IsExists", SqlDbType.Int);
                parm.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(parm);


                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    return IsExists();
    if (IsExists() == 1) {
        MessageBox.Show("Serials Already Exists!!");
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx"); }
    else if (IsExists() == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Serial Numbers have been updated.", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx"); }
}
```

Here is the stored proc:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_InsertReceiptSerials]
        @POPRCTNM CHAR(17), @ITEMNMBR CHAR(31), @SERLTNUM CHAR(21), @RecLineID INT, @RCPTLNNM INT, @IsExists INT OUTPUT

    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        DECLARE @RecCount INT
    --  DECLARE @IsExists INT

        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.vwSerialNumbers WHERE SERLNMBR = Right(@SERLTNUM,20) AND ITEMNMBR = @ITEMNMBR)
            BEGIN 
                SET @IsExists = 1
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO dbo.usr_ReceiptSerials(POPRCTNM, ITEMNMBR, SERLTNUM, FullSerialNumber, EntryDate, RecLineID, RCPTLNNM)
                VALUES (@POPRCTNM, @ITEMNMBR, Right(@SERLTNUM,20), @SERLTNUM,  GetDate(), @RecLineID, @RCPTLNNM)
                SET @RecCount = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.usr_ReceiptSerials  WHERE RecLineID = @RecLineID)
                UPDATE dbo.usr_ReceiptLine SET QTYSHPPD = @RecCount
                WHERE RecLineID = @RecLineID
                SET @IsExists = 0
            END
    END
```

Comment: What is the actual error you're receiving?

Comment: It adds them to the db and then gives me this error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Data.dll

I believe it is stuck in the loop

Comment: I just updated to show stored proc and calling said value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a simple recursion problem which is causing the stackoverflow.

```
=> return IsExists();
```

In your returns staement you're calling the same function. Remove this line if this is not part of any business logic.

Also, rather checking `if (IsExists() == 1)`

use:

`int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
Then do the evaluation on result:

```
   if (result == 1) {
        MessageBox.Show("Serials Already Exists!!");
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx"); }
    else if (result == 0) {
        MessageBox.Show("Serial Numbers have been updated.", "Important Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        Response.Redirect("Index.aspx"); }
```

For build error you must return an integer value that method is expecting. 
E.g. It could be `result` itself.

> Update:

In your case it seems you want to read the value of `Output` parameter. To read an output parameter value from Command object see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/290676/881798). Then `result` variable would be assigned by the `Output` parameter that you will read from SqlParameter after exeuction of Command.

Comment: I  just removed that line and now get a build error: not all paths return a value

Comment: `ExecuteNonQuery` only returns the number of rows affected. The OP has an output parameter for `exists`, so catching the return value doesn't help.

Comment: @DaveZych Updated the answer! I got it after looking at the stored proc. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! That was driving me crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Building upon the other answer:

```
public int IsExists() 
{
    int returnInt =0;
    foreach (GridViewRow row in gvSerials.Rows) 
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString)) 
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertReceiptSerials", con)) 
            {
            // /.../
            if whatever your testing is true:
            returnInt = 1;
            or
            return returnInt;

            or
            return 1;
            or wait until the end of the method if you want to add more stuff.
            }
        }
    }
    // Do any more stuff here.

    return returnInt();
    // Nothing beyond here is executed.

}
```

Anything you do after you return in a method, will not be executed. i.e. the method ends with the return, that value is then taken back to the calling method.