# ADO.NET what to use to set multiple output parameters - ExecuteScalar, ExecuteReader or ExecuteNonQuery or nothing?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have following working code. This has 1 input and two output parameters. Which ado.net method should I use?

```
OneInputTwoOutput oneInputTwoOutput = new OneInputTwoOutput();

var Param = new DynamicParameters();
Param.Add("@Input1", Input1);
Param.Add("@Output1", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
Param.Add("@Output2", dbType: DbType.Boolean, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

try
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["connectionString"]))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetOneInputTwoOutput", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Input1", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Input1;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Output1", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Output2", SqlDbType.Bit).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            con.Open();

            dealerStatus.Output1= (cmd.Parameters["@Output1"].Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["@Output1"].Value) : false);
            dealerStatus.Output2= (cmd.Parameters["@Output2"].Value != DBNull.Value ? Convert.ToBoolean(cmd.Parameters["@Output2"].Value) : false);

            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
catch (SqlException err)
{
}
```

I read this link:
[Get output parameter value in ADO.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net)

This suggests using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. But even not using this `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`, I am able to set the output parameters.

Can someone explain how? And what should be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty simple, really:

- if you want to return a **result set** with **exactly one row, one column** (e.g. from a `SELECT COUNT(*)...` operation or something similar), then use `ExecuteScalar()` (in brief: *result set - one row, one column*)
- if you want to return a **result set** with multiple row, multiple columns - then use `ExecuteReader()` to return a `SqlDataReader` that can then be used to iterate through the rows returned, and fetch all data (in brief: *result set - multiple rows, multiple columns for each row*)
- if anything else (if you run a command that **doesn't** return any result set), then use `ExecuteNonQuery()`. This is typically used for `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` operations, but it can also be used if your query just doesn't return a **result set**, but instead sets some output parameters (in brief: *no result set returned*)