# Identity Value returned as 0 using SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a contact info form in Visual Studio (using C#) that can be used to turn the contact into a customer, to do so I want to send the id from the contact that was just created to the other form and to do this I created a stored procedure that returns the id using `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. It works in SQL Server and returns the identity correctly but when I try to aquire it, convert the int into string and set it in a label for testing it reads as 0.

My stored procedure is as follows.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE IdentityTest
      @FirstName varchar(50),
      @LastName varchar(50),
      @id int output
AS
BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      INSERT INTO Employees (FirstName, LastName)
      VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName)

      SET @id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
      RETURN  @id
END
```

In my form.aspx.cs I have the following code to acess the DB.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     SqlCommand cons = new SqlCommand("IdentityTest", cncon);
     cons.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

     cons.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
     cons.Parameters.Add("@LastName", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
     cons.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);

     cons.Parameters["@FirstName"].Value = nom.Value;
     cons.Parameters["@LastName"].Value = dirclie.Value;
     cons.Parameters["@id"].Value = IdCliente;

     string IdClientesString = IdCliente.ToString();

     cncon.Open();
     cons.ExecuteNonQuery();

     Label1.Text = IdClientesString;
     cncon.Close();
}
```

Comment: See this answer to the duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/a/290772/27825

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the `@id` parameter as an **output** parameter in your C# code:

```
SqlParameter idParam = cons.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
idParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

and after executing your query, you need to **read out** the value:

```
cons.ExecuteNonQuery();
int newIdValue = Convert.ToInt32(cons.Parameters["@id"].Value);
```

Comment: Just tried it, no errors but the label reads as 0.