# Invalid index 0 for this OracleParameterCollection with Count=0

Tags: c#, oracle, system.data.oracleclient

```
public void BeginTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        this._keepalive = true;
        if (_oracleConnection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            _oracleConnection.Open();
            //_oracleConnection.Autocommit = false;
        this._transaction = this._oracleConnection.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _hasError = true;
        _ErrorMessage = ex.Message + "::" + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}

public void CommitTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        this._transaction.Commit();
        this._keepalive = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _hasError = true;
        _ErrorMessage = ex.Message + "::" + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}

public void RollbackTransaction()
{
    try
    {
        this._transaction.Rollback();
        this._keepalive = false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _hasError = true;
        _ErrorMessage = ex.Message + "::" + ex.StackTrace;
    }
}

public string ExecuteSPNonQuerySingleReturnValue(string storedProcName, object[] parameterValues, string outParameterName, bool useTransaction = false)
{
    _hasError = false; _ErrorMessage = "";
    string result = "";
    try
    {
        if (_oracleConnection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            _oracleConnection.Open();
        if (_oracleConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            OracleCommand objOraCommand = new OracleCommand();
            objOraCommand.Connection = _oracleConnection;
            objOraCommand.CommandText = storedProcName;
            objOraCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            if (useTransaction == true)
                objOraCommand.Transaction = this._transaction;
            OracleCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(objOraCommand);
            for (int i = 0; i < parameterValues.Length; i++)
            {
                //objOraCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter(parameterNames[i], OracleType.VarChar)).Value = (parameterValues[i] == null) ? DBNull.Value : parameterValues[i];
                // It threw exception over here. Below this line.
                objOraCommand.Parameters[i].Value = (parameterValues[i] == null) ? DBNull.Value : parameterValues[i];
                //objOraCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameterNames[i], (parameterValues[i] == null) ? DBNull.Value : parameterValues[i]);
            }
            objOraCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = objOraCommand.Parameters[outParameterName].Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _hasError = true;
        _ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (_oracleConnection.State == ConnectionState.Open && _keepalive == false)
        _oracleConnection.Close();
    }
    return result;
}
```

I am getting exception at this line.

```
objOraCommand.Parameters[i].Value = (parameterValues[i] == null) ? DBNull.Value : parameterValues[i];
```

Does anyone know what is the problem? It was working fine without transaction. This method started to give error right after adding transaction.

I am using built .Net oracle client library.

```
using System.Data.OracleClient;
```

Comment: You haven't added any parameters yet you try to accesss them. Index 0 is the first element. An empty parameter collection though has no parameters

Comment: This is the procedure i am calling PROCEDURE CHCCC_STSS (PSSS IN VARCHAR2, PCCC IN VARCHAR2,varReturnValue OUT VARCHAR2); and i am passing proper values to those parameter.

Comment: Please check any ADO.NET tutorial on how to use parameters, specially out parameters.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your demoralizing comment! I have tried out 100s of website and tutorials before posting it here.

Comment: Did you [check this similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/290652/get-output-parameter-value-in-ado-net). ADO.NET is the same whether you use the Oracle or SQL Server provider. This means that any tutorial on using parameters with SQL Server is equally valid for other providers.

Comment: Also, the documentation explains how to call commands with parameters  in [Configuring Parameters and Parameter Data Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: This code is working fine without transaction. It gives me an error when I add transaction. Try it once it will increase your knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

using `objOraCommand.Parameters.Add()` instead of `objOraCommand.Parameters[i].Value = xxxx`. And `parameterValues` should be `OracleParameter`type. more check this [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: PROCEDURE CHCCC_STSS (PSSS IN VARCHAR2, PCCC IN VARCHAR2,varReturnValue OUT VARCHAR2);

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CHCCC_STSS'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored This is the error i got.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there is no parameter in Parameters and you are trying to access its index, that is why its giving error. you should add parameter like o`bjOraCommand.Parameters.Add()`and you you want to try to access the value at `objOraCommand.Parameters[i].Value` and first add parameter to that location like as you do in list and array. and this error is not at all related to Transaction, my only advice would be to use Transaction properly not like this complicated code.